# html video tag is not working in iOS devices

Tags: html, ios, html5-video

The `video` HTML tag is not working with iOS devices.

I have tried the `playsinline` `muted` attributes with no results.

Here's the code that i have till the moment, with variations found from various questions around this issue but i couldn't get it working.

```
<video muted autoplay loop playsinline src="<?php echo THEME_IMAGES . '/video.mp4' ?>" type="video/mp4">
 <source src="<?php echo THEME_IMAGES . '/video.mov' ?>" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: There is no end tag for `<source>`. Remove that.

Comment: That what i originally used, but saw a comment here using closing tag for `source`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For some reason changing it to .mov file type and removing `source` tag worked, while it was working on other devices.

```
<video playsinline loop muted autoplay src="<?php echo THEME_IMAGES . '/video.mov' ?>" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

Comment: **(1)** _"For some reason changing it to .mov file type works..."_ Looks like your file was always called `video.mov` and you could see that, but somehow you chose to put `video.mp4` then be surprised it doesn't load anything. **(2)** Best to use `type="video/quicktime"` for MOV files. Though some browsers will accept either setting (since MP4 and MOV have same internal structure anyways).

Comment: In all the devices i tested it was working normally. For some reason iOS just liked .mov more than .mp4

Comment: _"iOS just liked `.mov` more..."_ Yes that's true. The MOV format is from Apple themselves so they'll favour it over others. Is there anything special about your MOV, like maybe it uses transparent video? or maybe it contains H.265/HEVC video? Just asking for learning purposes...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).